# Proper morphism sending coherent to coherent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Hello,

Is there a proof that the push forward by a proper morphism of Noetherian schemes sends coherent sheaves to coherent ones, without passing in the argument through projective morphisms?

Thank you,
Sasha

Comment: Well, you can use Chow's lemma, the result for projective morphisms, and the Leray spectral sequence to get it.  Or you can find a different proof here EGA III 3.2.1 here: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?id=PMIHES_1961__11_

Comment: @Parsa: If you use Chow's lemma, you are using the result for projective morphisms, which is what Sasha wants to avoid?

Comment: If your schemes are locally of finite type over a field k, Antoine Ducros gave a proof that meets your requirements (see arXiv:math/0612521). Basically, the result is known for proper rigid analytic spaces (it is a theorem of Kiehl), so one also gets it for analytifications of proper morphisms (analytifications are to be taken in Berkovich sense, over k endowed with the trivial absolute value) and for proper morphisms themselves.

Comment: @Timo: I wasn't sure what he meant by "without passing in the argument through projective morphisms" so I gave an approach assuming proper but not projective (allowing the result for projective) and referenced another proof using only proper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gerd Faltings, Finiteness of coherent cohomology for proper fppf stacks, J. Algebraic Geometry 12 (2003) 357–366